# Difference between these two gems "site_prism" and "page_object"

Tags: ruby, rspec, page-object-gem, site-prism

I have come across two projects one is with `WATIR` `cucumber feature files` and `step definitions` and another one is `Rspec`, ``` capybara`` without ```step definitions`and`feature files`.

In `WATIR` project `page_object` was used and in `capybara` `site_prism gem` was used.

1. What is the difference between two?
2. Can't we use `page_object` in `capybara` would that be incorrect approach? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between the two is supported underlying drivers, which is the part that actually interacts with the browser.

- SitePrism supports Capybara.
- Page-Object supports Watir-Webdriver and Selenium-Webdriver.

As each gem makes assumptions about the API of the driver, you cannot use unsupported drivers - ie you cannot use the Page-Object gem with Capybara.

Aside from that, it is mainly API preferences. Both gems are for creating page object models. However, the syntax for defining the page object and the methods the page object has will differ based on the preferences of each gem's author.